# TARGET_JDK in start.sh file is not recognising JDK in JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, java-8, backend, web-development-server, java-17

I am trying to update my spring boot project from java8 to java17 and also update infra to jdk17

Below in my server jdk1.8 is installed by default, when I installed jdk17 it got installed and JAVA_HOME and PATH variables are updated to jdk17

But when I type java -version its still giving jdk1.8, and my spring boot app is not recognising jdk17 its still recognising jdk1.8

[text]([by default there is jdk1.8 in /user/java/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvPeS.jpg))

[Installed jdk17 got installed at path /opt/bgwadmin/java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osz7K.jpg)

[JAVA_HOME and PATH variables are updated according to jdk17](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifZBj.jpg)

[But java -version is still giving jdk1.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdznh.jpg)

[I have set java target as jdk17 for application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZOy2.jpg)

[App is unable to recognise jdk17](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYwq0.jpg)

Please help me out with this, not able to understand what is going wrong

Comment: What java executable is picked by the shell depends solely on what's in your path environment variable. Presumably the java 8 path is still in there and found first.

Comment: Posting regular screenshots of code, errors, logs, or other text is already bad (see [ask]); but yours are next level bad.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you have the right version of JDK inside the /latest folder. (Because according to your screenshots, I can see OpenJDK folder below the latest folder. So high chances are there that you have given the JAVA_HOME path wrongly.
2. Make sure you have mentioned JDK version in your project's pom.xml correctly.

   `<properties> <java.version>17</java.version> </properties>`